# Concurrency issues with Gunicorn + Firebase + Kubernetes in Google Cloud

Tags: python, firebase, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I am currently developing an API in Python 3 with Django that is mounted on Kubernetes in Google Cloud, using asynchronous workers with Gunicorn (Gevent).

The problem is that I have a Post method which makes a validation to Firebase to search for a specific user, when I performed load tests (only 10 concurrent users) I see a degeneration in the response times, the weird thing is that this does not happen to me locally, only in the Google cloud environment.

PS: for handling Firebase I'm using the Python library called firebase_admin.